# jquery more click function using data attribute

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have to link multiple contents (result of a db query). I tried using more than one click function, but site was really slow, so I tried doing this.

The HTML element written by PHP:

```
<img id="click" src="images/like.png" alt="" width="80%" data-event="'.$rows[$i][id].'"/>
```

The jQuery Code:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function()

    {

        $('#click').click(function()
        {

            var id = $(this).data('event');
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari

                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();                   
                xmlhttp.open("GET","likes.php?eid="+id+"&ip=IPADDRESS",true);
                xmlhttp.send();

            }
            document.location = "index.php";

        });

    });
</script>
```

But it only works on the first element...

Comment: IDs **must** be unique. Try a class instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#click")
```

Will return only the first element. As IDs need to be unique.

Instead change it  to `class` and it will work

```
$(".click")
```

this will return you list of all images

But still you can do with the above HTML unmodified also, but i won't recommend it

```
$("img[id^=click]") // don't use this ever , just to know even this will work
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code by :

```
<img class="like" src="images/like.png" alt="" width="80%" data-event="'.$rows[$i][id].'"/>
```

And your jQuery code

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function()

    {

        $('.like').click(function()
        {

            var id = $(this).data('event');
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari

                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();                   
                xmlhttp.open("GET","likes.php?eid="+id+"&ip=IPADDRESS",true);
                xmlhttp.send();

            }
            document.location = "index.php";

        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Сan be a reason to use ID instead of class
Try change `#click` `.click`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I downvoted your answer as it is unclear what you want the asker to do. You also seem to have mixed up `id` and `class` in your answer.